# Entity Framework 4.1 Persisting a getter

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, getter

Lots of Like for EF4.1, but have got stuck on doing this!

I want to end up with a class like this, where EF handles both properties, and they are both in the database.

```
public class myClass 
{
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public string status { get { return priority > 10 ? "Low" : "High" } }
}
```

1) When I generate the model from the database, I need to somehow inject the status calculation into its property.
2) Hopefully the solution works when I regenerate my model from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot persist such property. It is business logic (computed property). If you want to save it the property must have setter because EF will try to set it when materializing entity loaded from the database but once you expose a setter your getter will not make sense and this logic will have to be moved elsewhere.

Edit:

The workaround is to wrap your `Status` logic into helper extension method:

```
public static IsHighPriority(this IQueryable<MyClass> query)
{
     return query.Where(x => x.Priority > 10);
}
```

Now you can use it in the query like:

```
var query = from x in context.MyClasses.IsHighPriority()
            where ...
            select x;
```

Comment: Hmm.  I approached this from a perspective of how far up the business layers to push the IQueryable.  I found that if I used the status property in an IQueryable then I get an error because the field is not in the database, hence the desire to persist it to the DB.  If this is not allowed, then I have often seen this logic put into the database as Computed Columns, which EF can handle, however, under your argument, putting Business logic into the DB would be even worse.  You left a tantalising "Elsewhere", any suggestions?